# Swift: Array of equatable generic type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, types, generic-collections

I have been the last days fighting with some issues regarding generics on Swift, and I don't find a way to figure out how to achieve this:

- I have a class `class Store<S: State>` where `State` is a simple protocol which extends Equatable `protocol State: Equatable`.
- I have a class `Logger` where I want to store an array of `Stores` to keep track of each change on them and compare their `State` with their old values, being able to check what changes in each iteration.

For this, I need to store an array of  **Any Kind of Store** in my logger class. The problem comes when I try to use a `val storeArray = [Store<Any>]`, it doesn't work because Any is not an `Equatable` type, and I will need them to extend `Equatable` or `NSObject` to be able to compare the states between them.

Is possible to achieve this in Swift? Or find out another way to compare 2 items without make a generic extend a `Equatable` protocol?

In case you wanna check the implementation :

**State :**

```
protocol State: Equatable {
}
```

**Store :**

```
class Store<S: State> {

    private var _initialState: S
    private var _state: S
    private var processor = PublishSubject<S>()

    init(initialState: S) {
        _initialState = initialState
        _state = initialState
    }

    var state: S {
        get {
            return _state
        }
        set(value) {
            if (value != state) {
                _state = value
                processor.onNext(value)
            }
        }
    }

    func initialState() -> S {
        return _initialState
    }

    /// Initialize the store. Called after all stores instances are ready.
    func initialize() {
        //TODO Check if its possible to force an override over a method
        preconditionFailure("This method must be overridden")
    }
}
```

After the suggestion of **Vadian** I have tried to move it to a protocol with an associate type:

```
protocol Store: class {
    associatedtype State : StateDelegate
    var processor : PublishSubject<State> { get }
    var _state : State { get set }
    var state: State { get set }
    func initialState() -> State
    func flowable() -> Observable<State>
    func initialize() -> Void
}

extension Store {

    var state: State {
        get {
            return _state
        }
        set(value) {
            if (value != state) {
                _state = value
                processor.onNext(value)
            }
        }
    }

    func flowable() -> Observable<State> {
        return processor.startWith(state)
    }

    func initialState() -> State {
        return State.init()
    }
}
```

But I retrieve the next error when I try to create an `[Store]` array:
`Protocol 'Store' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Comment: Consider to use a protocol with associated type rather than a generic constrained to a protocol.

Comment: Are you saving different `State` types in the `Store`s in that array (something like `storeArray = [Store<State1>(), Store<State2>()]`)? If so, `Equatable` won't work anyway because it requires the two compared objects to be of the same type (more or less).

Comment: @vadian I tried already to use a protocol for the `Store`, but when I try to use an array of that type, but I retrieve the next error : `Protocol 'Store' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Comment: That's the idea @dr_barto but I will just compare `States` of `Stores` of the same type, but I need the generic array to iterate, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand your problem now. How about this solution:

Instead of letting `State` conform to `Equatable`, you add your own custom equality check to the protocol; this way you can store your states in an array (`var states: [State]`). The drawback is that you cannot use generics but instead have to type-check in code, like in the good old times.

For example, a simple version of the `State` protocol:

```
protocol State {
  func isEqualTo(_ other: State) -> Bool
}
```

Your concrete state types have to implement `isEqualTo` and perform a type check before testing equality:

```
struct State1: State {
  var foo: String
  func isEqualTo(_ other: State) -> Bool {
    guard let state1 = other as? State1 else { return false }
    return self.foo == state1.foo
  }
}
```

Now you can store your states in an array and e.g. check if a new state already is contained:

```
let states: [State] = [ State1(foo: "hi"), State2(bar: 42), State1(foo: "bye")]
let newState = State2(bar: 42)
let containsNewState = states.contains { $0.isEqualTo(newState )}
```